# substring extraction in bash

Tags: bash, substring

iamnewbie: this code is inefficient but it should extract the substring, the problem is with last echo statement,need some insight.

```
    function regex {


    #this function gives the regular expression needed



    echo -n \'

    for (( i = 1 ; i <= $1  ; i++ ))
         do
           echo -n . 
        done

    echo -n '\('

    for (( i = 1 ; i <= $2 ; i++ ))
         do
           echo -n . 
         done

     echo -n '\)'
     echo -n \'

     }
     # regex function ends


      echo "Enter the string:"

      read stg
      #variable stg holds the string entered

      if [ -z "$stg" ] ; then

           echo "Null string"

      exit

      else

           echo "Length of the $stg is:"

           z=`expr "$stg" : '.*' `

           #variable z holds the length of given string

           echo $z

      fi

      echo "Enter the number of trailing characters to be extracted from  $stg:"

      read n

      m=`expr $z - $n `
      #variable m holds an integer value which is equal to total length - length of characters to be extracted

      x=$(regex $m $n)

      echo ` expr "$stg" : "$x" `
      #the echo statement(above) is just printing a newline!! But not the result
```

What I intend to do with this code is, if I enter "racecar" and give "3" , it should display "car" which are the last three characters. Instead of displaying "car" its just printing a newline. Please correct this code rather than giving a better one.

Comment: The problem is that your output contains a trailing newline? That's what `echo` does. Try `printf %s $(expr ...)`?

Comment: @EtanReisner: as written, the echo is kinda pointless, except for normalizing whitespace. Probably not the problem being referred to, though. I think the problem is the apostrophes manually inserted into $regex. There really needs to be a canonical answer for that syndrome.

Comment: but i have used echo -n in regex function

Comment: Not on the last line you didn't.

Comment: @rici It forces a newline at the end. I don't know if `expr` does that itself (though it very well might). But you are, obviously, correct in that it also normalizes whitespace. The single quotes in the regex string returned by `regex` are likely another problem (unless expr evaluates those itself).

Comment: @Etan i tried printf %s $(expr . . .) but i didn't get the answer. hope you can post the changes made , so that the code works

Comment: What is the problem exactly? Can you be more clear? Is the problem that your last line outputs the result and a newline? Is the problem that your pattern doesn't match? Something else?

Comment: well i am not even getting the result but just a newline, once i enter an integer, the execution stops ( i am running ubuntu on vmware, i have bash shell)

Comment: @EtanReisner: `expr` outputs a newline at the end of whatever value it prints. If it didn't, it would be even more surprising -- and it already has enough gotchas to sink a tanker. `echo $(command)` has the interesting feature of printing a blank line if `command` prints nothing; otherwise, it just normalizes whitespace. But in this case, `expr` is printing a single newline, so the `echo` in `echo $(expr ...)` is the identity function. `echo $(command)` is just another instance of the UUOC phenomenon.

Comment: @rici Yes. I was fully expecting that `expr` might not output a newline as part of its fleet of oddities (but more to the point using `echo` would then actually be useful in that line if used with `-n` which could very well have been the point here).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although you didn't ask for a better solution, it's worth mentioning:

```
$ n=3
$ stg=racecar
$ echo "${stg: -n}"
car
```

Note that the space after the `:` in `${stg: -n}` is *required*. Without the space, the parameter expansion is a default-value expansion rather than a substring expansion. With the space, it's a substring expansion; `-n` is interpreted as an arithmetic expression (which means that `n` is interpreted as `$n`) and since the result is a negative number, it specifies the number of characters from the end to start the substring. See the [Bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) for details.

---

Your solution is based on evaluating the equivalent of:

```
expr "$stg" : '......\(...\)'
```

with an appropriate number of dots. It's important to understand what the above bash syntax actually means. It invokes the command `expr`, passing it three arguments:

arg 1: the contents of the variable `stg`

arg 2: `:`

arg 3: `......\(...\)`

Note that there are no quotes visible. That's because the quotes are part of bash *syntax*, not part of the argument values.

If the value of `stg` had enough characters, the result of the above `expr` invocation would be to print out the 7th, 8th and 9th character of the value of  stg`. Otherwise, it would print a blank line, and fail.

But that's not what you are doing. You're creating the regular expression:

```
'......\(...\)'
```

which has single quotes in it. Since single-quotes are not special characters in a regex, they match themselves; in other words, that pattern will match a string which starts with a single quote, followed by nine arbitrary characters, followed by another single quote. And if the string does match, it will print the three characters prior to the second single-quote.

Of course, since the regular expression you make has a `.` for every character in the target string, it won't match the target even if the target started and begun with a single-quote, since there would be too many dots in the regex to match that.

If you don't put single quotes into the regex, then your program will work, but I have to say that few times have I seen such an intensely circuitous implementation of the substring function. If you're not trying to win an obfuscated bash competition (a difficult challenge since most production bash code is obfuscated by nature), I'd suggest you use normal bash features instead of trying to do everything with regexen.

One of those is the syntax to determine the length of a string:

```
$ stg=racecar
$ echo ${#stg}
7
```

(although, as shown at the beginning, you don't actually even need that.)

Comment: I removed the quotes and the program worked !!! Thank you for your patience and insight

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
$ n=3
$ string="racecar"
$ [[ "$string" =~ (.{$n})$ ]]
$ echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
car
```

This looks for the last `n` characters at the end of the line. In a script:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Enter a string: " string
read -p "Enter the number of characters you want from the end: " n
[[ "$string" =~ (.{$n})$ ]]
echo "These are the last $n characters: ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
```

You may want to add some more error handling, but this'll do it.

Comment: BASH_REMATCH is a variable set by bash when doing when doing regular expressions (like `[[ ... =~ ... ]]`) with or without group capturing, like the `(.{$n})` above. The parenthesis "capture" a group, the first of which is in index 1, the next is in index 2, etc. You could probably just use `${BASH_REMATCH[0]}` in this case, which will return the entire match, which is necessarily only three characters, so you probably don't even need grouping/capturing. And this was probably too much explanation in a comment.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure you need loops for this task. I wrote some example to get two parameters from user and cut the word according to it.

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter some word? " -e stg
#variable stg holds the string entered
if [ -z "$stg" ] ; then
  echo "Null string"
  exit 1
fi

read -p "Enter some number to set word length? " -e cutNumber
# check that cutNumber is a number
if ! [ "$cutNumber" -eq "$cutNumber" ]; then
  echo "Not a number!"
  exit 1
fi
echo "Cut first n characters:"
echo ${stg:$cutNumber}
echo 
echo "Show first n characters:"
echo ${stg:0:$cutNumber}

echo "Alternative get last n characters:"
echo -n "$stg" | tail -c $cutNumber
echo
```

Example:

```
Enter some word? TheRaceCar
Enter some number to set word length? 7
Cut first n characters:
Car

Show first n characters:
TheRace
Alternative get last n characters:
RaceCar
```

Comment: works well, can you inform me about if ! [ "$cutNumber" -eq "$cutNumber" ]

Comment: -eq is an integer comparison. It means equal to. It works only for numbers, so it is a simple way to check if something is a number. [tldp](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html). [ ! EXPR ] True if EXPR is false. [Bash-Beginners-Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html)